# UIView Setting Constraints Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am kind of new to iOS and don't yet understand Constraints quite well. I am adding a set of dynamic views to my view controller which by default contains a scrollview and a container view on top. Everything is working fine and I was managing to add them below each other using the following:

```
TheView.frame = CGRectMake(5, CGFloat(position), self.view.frame.size.width-10, 40); //position is incremented so that they are below each other
```

But when I turn the phone to landscape, the views do not take the width of the main view so I added the following to the views:

```
TheView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide // contentView is the container view
    TheView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).active = true
    TheView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

This made the views dynamically change their width when I rotate the device but they are now overlapping and I can't seem to find out how can I set them to be placed below each other like how they were.

**UPDATE:**

I removed the scrollview and everything from storyboard and added a scrollview and stack view programatically.

in viewdidload:

```
ScrollView = UIScrollView()
        ScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(ScrollView)

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": ScrollView]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": ScrollView]))


        stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
        stackView.spacing   = 26.0
        stackView.axis = .Vertical
        ScrollView.addSubview(stackView)


        ScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
        ScrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
```

adding the dynamic views:

```
for loop...

let Description = UILabel()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(Description)

let Value = UITextField()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(Value)
```

the views are added successful as before and there is scrolling. also the views are filling the stack view (width) **but still not in landscape.**

Comment: Landscape orientation is also handled at the `UIVewController` level - see `supportedInterfaceOrientation`-  and at your application level (see supported orientations on your app target) Does the screen rotate - with the status bar - when you turn into landscape ?

Comment: sorry for late reply.. yes it does but i don't understand how this is related. the supported interface orientation are portrait, landscape left, and right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot at the same time:

- define a `frame` for your views
- define a set of constraints for these views

You do either one or the other.

You seem to be using iOS 9 APIs `constraintEqualToAnchor` , so you could as well put the 2 views you want to stack into a `UIStackView`, this would certainly be the simplest solution.

If you needed to support older versions of iOS (7, 8), this only mean you didn't defined enough constraints to place your views.
`TheView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor)` => this one places `TheView` left side (well, 'leading', as it can depend on the direction of the language displayed - e.g. it would be right for arabic)
`TheView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.trailingAnchor)` constraints the other side.

You have 2 horizontal constraints, so what you miss are 2 other constraints, for vertical axis.

One of these constraints might be `topAnchor` or `bottomAnchor` (depending on where is TheView - By the way, UpperCase for instance variables is quite uncommon :)

The other constraint might be defined between `TheView` and the other subview, something like

`let viewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: TheView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)` , if you want to place `TheView` below `scrollView`

Beware that `UIScrollView` behave a little differently with Auto-layout.
You have to give it one set of constraints with views outside its hierarchy (to constraint the scrollview `bounds`) and you can use another set of constraints to place the scrollView's subviews (and this way, constraint its `contentSize`) (see [Apple Technical Note on how to layout UIScrollView with constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

Comment: i tried the stack view, but now i can't add the constraints and when rotating the device, the added views won't take the stack view's width

Comment: A stackView is a replacement for constraints, so if you use one, you don't need to define any constraints. Look at `UiStackView`properties : `distribution` and `alignement`, they're used to say how your views should fill the space, respectively along the axis of the stackView and perpendicular to it.

Comment: thank you for your time @Vinzz. i will look up into this. But what i meant is i added the stack view and removed the constraints... rotated the device and the added views did not fill the view so i tried adding back the constraints and the app crashed.

Comment: I understood... don't put any constraints - as UIStackView is a replacement for constraints when your layout fits what stackView can do - just try to adjust the stackView properties to get the visual result you want

Comment: i am going to update my question and show what i did so far